# Extraer el mayor valor de lista de listas de números enteros, usando de comprensión de listas en python

Tags: python, lista

Haciendo uso de comprensión de listas y dado una lista de listas de números enteros devuelva el máximo de cada lista: por ejemplo
[[2, **4**, 1], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,**8**], [100,**250**,43]]

El programa debe  devolver el mayor elemento de  cada sublista
(señalado en negrita).

realice este codigo con un bucle

```
lista = [[2, 4, 1], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [100,250,43]]

for sublista in lista:
    max_values = max(sublista)
    print(max_values)
```

quisiera hacerlo comprensión de listas, seria mas optimo.... please help me!!!

Comment: `maxValues = [max(i) for i in lista]` o si solo quieres imprimir `[print(max(i)) for i in lista]`

Comment: Excelente gracias me habia bloqueado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La comprensión es solo una forma abreviada de escribir un par de instrucciones que involucran `for` y a veces algún condicional `if`. Recuerda, no necesariamente un código más corto es más eficiente, aunque en este caso da igual, puesto que son las mismas instrucciones.
Tu código para convertir debería ser este:

```
max_values = []
for sublista in lista:
    max_values.append(max(sublista))
```

Reescrito en comprensión, será:

```
max_values = [max(sublista) for sublista in lista]
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Diomer si te ayudó acepta la respuesta de @aeportugal como correcta para cerrar la pregunta